# add images to excel sheets using DDE

Tags: delphi, dde

I am working on a Delphi project, where i need to export values to excel sheets.
My project supports two ways of accomplishing this:
1) using thied party dll that manages the sheet creation
2) using built in dde, and executing commands over this.

Both ways work nice, but now i want to add support for exporting images to excel sheets. using the first way, this was easily accomplished.

My question is how can I add images to excel sheet, using a DDE command? A full list of all supported dde commands, would also be appreciated. I have come to [this](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/23/170290.html) but it doesn't seem to solve my problem....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figuring out the proper syntax for OLE communication with Excel can be a real pain or impossible. I've never found complete documentation on how to do it from Delphi. I usually end up doing a lot of trial and error testing, adding and removing parentheses and square brackets, etc.  It doesn't help that the error messages from Excel for ill-formed syntax are worthless.

I'd suggest that you consider a hybrid approach where you use Delphi to start macros in Excel, previously poking arguments into a hidden (xlVeryHidden) worksheet if necessary.  You can then do everything in VBA, which opens up a world of sample code and support (MrExcel.com forums are an excellent source of help, for example.)

You're aware of Deborah Pate's site, no: http://www.djpate.freeserve.co.uk/AutoExcl.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with only DDE.

I believe the correct approach is not DDE but OLE Automation (COM IDispatch interface).  DDE is only useful for linking your app to another app via its three main read/write/execute commands and so the capabilities are more limited than OLE Automation. You can be a DDE client and you can connect to Excel. Excel can be a DDE server or DDE client. In this case you could use Excel and write text easily using DDE.

I do not believe you can put bitmap image information into a DDE write, however, but you can write text, numbers and formulas.  I have used DDE heavily with Excel and Delphi, and have never seen any indication that it is possible.  DDE has three basic operations:

- peek  (read)
- poke (write)
- execute (call function)

If you had asked how to do it with OLE Automation, that would be another matter, and would be relatively easy, with Delphi, since Delphi supports COM and OLE Automation fluently.

Robert Frank's answer seems good too. You could possibly use VBA macrosand invoke them from DDE Execute but it's beyond my capabilities to suggest how.

Answer (score -1):

In my case it worked with the following command:

`EXCEL -> SYSTEM -> [INSERT.PICTURE("C:\temp\picture.jpg")]`